# delete one specific tag in metadata completely

Tags: exiftool

A photo has many tags and values, one of which is:

```
Contrast                        : Normal
```

As a test to remove a tag, I ran the following:

```
exiftool -Contrast=  -overwrite_original myfile.jpg
```

...but all it did was set the tag to 0:

```
Contrast                        : 0
```

Which exiftool command will remove the tag *completely*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sony group is in a class known as `MakerNotes`, proprietary tags added by various camera manufacturers which are used to hold various camera settings beyond what is normally available in just EXIF data. See [FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) for the command to look at all possible data and groups in a file.  Exiftool has the ability to edit many of these tags from various camera manufacturers but they cannot be individually created or deleted.  See [FAQ #23](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q23), last paragraph of Note #2.

To delete the `MakerNotes`, you must delete the entire block.  This can be done with
`exiftool -MakerNotes= file.jpg`
See [FAQ #8](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q8)

Take note that under **no** circumstance do you want to do this to any type of RAW file, such as a NEF or CR2.  This will make the file unrenderable, as MakerNote data is required to figure out how to decode the image data.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is a lot deeper than I imagined, it turns out that exiftool has groups and families of tags and they are not even the same thing!

[This](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=4625.0) forum discussion suggests that certain tags can only be removed if you remove a whole group or family, they cannot be removed individually.

From [here](https://exiftool.org/examples.html) there is  command:

```
exiftool -a -u -g1 a.jpg
```

which prints *all meta information in an image, including duplicate and unknown tags, sorted by group (for family 1).*

I think this is why 'Contrast' won't let itself be deleted.

In this case, 'Contrast' is in a group or family called 'Sony'

Tried the following:

```
exiftool -Sony=  myfile.jpg -overwrite_original
```

but it said

```
Warning: Sorry, Sony is not writable
Nothing to do.
```

This at least sheds some light on what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The command you use should work. Here is a test:

```
exiftool.exe  _M2A4595.jpg|findstr ISO
ISO                             : 100

exiftool.exe -ISO= _M2A4595.jpg
    1 image files updated
exiftool.exe  _M2A4595.jpg|findstr ISO
<empty line>
```